# "Мы еще не знакомы". Писать "не" слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> Мы кажется с тобой ещё не знакомы, но если что, все зовут меня Скай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сочетании с "ещё" ***не/знакомы***  может писаться и слитно, и раздельно.

[Слитное написание встречается и в школьных учебниках](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CjrqAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=QOB2Vbb1L8H9ywO164DACw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%22&f=false):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=====

**P.S.** Не забудьте выделить запятыми вводное слово "кажется":

*Мы, **кажется,** с тобой ещё не/знакомы…*

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[Повтор вопроса: Частица не: слитно или раздельно?](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=714.wytCXviYsLtVMjAMnfVm2PouZ0a27GdzfrmSpI7yDu_h7Au5mg0ygLOIiAm0M2kpLtivo8aQmSyyRMBnv7z-BIGJKtmVRx7OWrGJNW0BLm4.b52ee2ab573105fe50c9e8cc8570a7bcce8c221a&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9WXvvF5boevFhq0K1rI8k7SsuDjYxgt73A&data=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&b64e=2&sign=c5719519ab8a2f3638ed0d2f03329204&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQYtNprRPFzufqudLJZKAOLwoDTdQIxazSeWiChev90bYFecXuYsoEILhHBOkQH19r6cXAL-624aHx_LcC3otFcP7gyTkMXcdWHLkfSbdE7ATR49v0ZvAvMsKt8MNpXZ7yNQu96PqM42COkYqFQNrSccwvczOlGWp3lfsKLLeWBDQ6RlUuTyo2aW4bXDCZTc-Zj38lkZkUQHK&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCHgI4h6Y0hbtoes4Cfdh8gDwhmALuWOzyRCJbVRdq6n9zAu3Mtlar6QgpI_nDYMEXpUAQkVtZ-smrltTt91_1ssVdhFGQs5JzQ3C0EpJoSIyLU_NaBubQgii9GoKaqBx6YtnPpj1wcJwnD1f37TbBSSC2iA9TOu1AEzyC03QP1p0ZQoChW3-CUnJNpEq4l0dM9qdZkxJM8khpr6h-CuAElpVuhD5Jv1gdr4g7_Rm16w1B0pDBEXJ6rPM0BIXv7kp87Bq6hTaAMdKZ7fTIl_VYDLDi11I3lEsTukLf22Q-91A_V48MA9g8RgJ3V05i__x2Uap61eFt5JykgX-BtZ2XpnqsnI1MP2UfwpC4REL4Y0_O_vZY1xCHAJBAquukFheaalSSb6_5P6onQXw02uPwQpEKun_3sfhY581DSa8OVsusmIo-loq6rWL_ojgttkNaDVaxpTXMw5xfq7flVlhacjj-BsP5jD1CJntIIDvVI3rZd-fUP3OosQ7rYEQF6UE838qnC8_ZYmjgKaPsvA4vMiCc0HhR0Y7DxagkLVwOQAff3SPlSDVuEzrcUx-Vhx2VW7_jzI4StfoehnH9oc9pdhCFWv-iUnTHkKzhz5HGOTRRwxslPr3lAYzmXWV8e-mvrbIjuT1USYVYK8ROpCQdzSOcYoqlyKfJhFmSGuldRjVsVd0uvvYzQMv-YkSxLsXLv-LoCm5Hjvjnr_Kzn8yBMbaa0RoDsGEdB-TqCbggs0vQ0yOkjDnDSZgpJ0tzcNNNoLxoeZzuD-hCFCYFV_7PDDYmnXbzma6YWig7hPsbXBKHCb9WRgxfCe4fOfETjEl6q3MKjfwVzGPKES2ZSeIWEzGWNMbAf6dzb9TE6Fn9Ufal6xai2s239dz5mIO46O8Qa_ej37HneUZIHgkvW_UtzGlYCDMQ2pgNXQUOFu6T1OX647yx_uSSDhxx7tsYDjEO7dpFPoDkfIkIRTUEoaFq3-hHHgZ8InpdjXa34-csV5UK-dbvxC8AUBLotZa1kp3UTWZ_EBnIhWRBPONH216qna_Jrgm2UCPPL1VSkn_XI0DYcOcd2Ntz13nTt3L-rI6d0kFA4QvPsS57f1lfTbbyWj5NH72c3XxpqltC56IS7sXAeEfHARoWDAt-2Xy7o1yVZCdRoUTY2F8Ivb-L4s64BvNYjqq06zCuA60dQP7ZYTlYdgEIioT_KVaPr4QX3Rd1uJS3d3Fl0UkJch-jGvaQ6LCPkmCZHIqoCLqbg0rHf5FYApljXFQcLTIscq1bx6-q0O5c2WoG6puW8GjCSXqfowlytQzRC_MfH_cZHI_5kppkKlQCEWRsNp3KRnvv51h9yt80bpe8_V0WaH5hvtZC8w8ZWZVsepxzVsrfrqJwfWNL3FdBiinEDTkcWSxhi9KTpAuLX34z7Zi_RJgvGz0c313yZl1L8wIDZMP6Z8wOV1b5I2TmX7O9xsmij0FLH_Y1vdBnSFZ3B10SonWnZn8KAUoDhCYkCP3prnZaQuMC5wTolWlV3CCVmwq14nhiLa3IpLDou9XfHEsR4JOJK0n9ZVaEC1DgWeyp8bmUaisAIWBR8ktz2P-5O9F-CEdcuxb1Ob_O7gNC6xC76lxx8f2tDFACrU9PkfXN2Bi8C-OLz4fm51j-9gyF0s5zLhn3MvwM4WkRE1rECY_q9pnkTtBlTKd0QC2zHQ1opDSDtP5tqugVZhqEhRk8pLU_Zuwfr270dqi1w_hTC_2WlJ09QkkY_Q&l10n=ru&cts=1433856147973&mc=4.188518597130077)

> Примечание 1. Раздельно пишется не с прилагательными только при наличии таких пояснительных слов, которые усиливают отрицание, к ним относятся:

отрицательные местоимения и наречия (начинающиеся с ни): никому не известный писатель, никому и нигде не знакомые песни, никому не нужные сведения, ничем не привлекательная картина, ни в каком отношении не правильные выводы, но: в заявлении истца не было ничего незнакомого (местоимение ничего не поясняет слово незнакомого, а само определяется им: ничегокакого? — незнакомого);

частицы далеко, отнюдь, вовсе: далеко не известный писатель, отнюдь не знакомые песни, вовсе не интересная книга.

***Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. Орфография и пунктуация: справочник.- М.: "Неолит", 2001***

Answer (score 0):

В сочетаниях "не знакомы",  "еще не знакомы" НЕ пишется раздельно, но встречается и слитное написание: мы незнакомы".

Наречие "еще" влияет на написание НЕ, в текстах вариант "мы еще незнакомы" практически не встречается, но словарь допускает такую форму.

Схемы образования слова: знакомый - знаком - не знаком; знакомый - незнакомый - незнаком

Answer (score 0):

Согласно школьной трактовке правила о НЕ с краткой формой прилагательного, краткое прилагательное с НЕ пишется так же, как полное. А в полной форме наречие ЕЩЕ на прилагательное не влияет, а потому пишем НЕ СЛИТНО: МЫ ЕЩЕ НЕЗНАКОМЫ.